# Issue with using the number_to_currency helper with pounds format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I am trying to leverage the number_to_currency helper on my ActiveAdmin application to show an amount in pounds.

I have tried the following code and it's throwing an error.

```
column "GBP", :sortable => "GBP" do |dailydeal|
   number_to_currency (dailydeal.currency_GBP, unit: "&pound;")
end
```

I've tried playing around the " and ' but it still throws an error.

When I do not add the :unit => £) it works fine.

Error Message:

/home/action/workspace/myapp/app/admin/dailydeal.rb:38: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')' number_to_currency (dailydeal.currency_GBP, :unit => "£") ^ /home/action/workspace/myapp/app/admin/dailydeal.rb:38: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end /home/action/workspace/myapp/app/admin/dailydeal.rb:65: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end

I am using ActiveAdmin pre 1.0 and Rails 4.1.4

Thanks for your help!

Full code below:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Dailydeal, :as => "Daily Deal" do
  scope :all, :default => true
  scope :AboveAverage
  scope :BelowAverage

  config.sort_order = "EndDate_desc"


  index do
      column "Product Name" do |dailydeal|
        link_to dailydeal.ProductName, dailydeal.ProductLink, :target => "_blank"
       end

    column "Unit Price", :UnitPrice
    column "Unit Sold", :UnitSold

    column "Average Percentage", :sortable => "Average Percentage" do |dailydeal|
      number_to_percentage dailydeal.averagechange_UnitSold
    end

    column "Start Date", :StartDate
    column "End Date", :EndDate

    column :Revenue, :sortable => :Revenue do |dailydeal|
      div :class => "revenue" do
        number_to_currency dailydeal.Revenue
       end
    end

     column "Image" do |dailydeal|
       link_to (image_tag dailydeal.ImageURL), dailydeal.ImageURL, :target => "_blank", class: 'fancybox'
      end

    column :Company
    column :Country

    column "GBP", :sortable => "GBP" do |dailydeal|
       number_to_currency (dailydeal.currency_GBP, unit: "&pound;")
       end
    end

    column "EUR", :sortable => "EUR" do |dailydeal|
      number_to_currency (dailydeal.currency_EUR)
    end

    actions

  end

  filter :ProductName, :label => "Search", :as => :string, filters: ['contains']
  filter :UnitPrice, :label => "Unit Price"
  filter :Revenue
  filter :Company, :as => :select

 #  filter :StartDate, :label => "Start Date", :as => :date
 # filter :EndDate, :label => "End Date", :as => :date

  permit_params :ProductName, :ProductLink, :ImageURL, :UnitPrice, :UnitSold, :StartDate, :EndDate, :Revenue, :Company, :Country, :Merchant


#  sidebar :Currencies do
 #     f.input :design, :as => :select, :collection => ["a","b","c"]

  #  end

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the correct code below, I just needed to remove the space between number_to_currency and the (

```
column "GBP", :sortable => "GBP" do |dailydeal|
       number_to_currency(dailydeal.currency_GBP, unit: "£")
    end
```